# Is $f(n) + O(f(n)) = \theta(f(n))$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics

I've been asked to show whether this is always, never or sometimes true.

I think I understand that in this situation, $O(f(n))$ can be treated as a macro for some function $g(n)$. So if the equation is true, we can write:

$c_1f(n) \le f(n) + g(n) \le c_2f(n)$

For large enough $n$

But I'm not sure where to go from there, to prove whether the equation is true or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counterexample: $f(n)-f(n)=0\ne\theta(f(n))$ unless $f(n)=0$ for large $n$. (Clearly, $-f(n)=O(f(n))$.) Thus, sometimes this is not true. On the other hand, $f(n)+0=\theta(f(n))$, so in this case the claim is true. Thus, the answer is "sometimes true".

Comment: I would have written this myself, but you beat me to it.

Comment: @GEdgar: Sorry, Professor, for having done so;)

Comment: This made things much clearer, thank you. So if we can say that f(n) is non-negative (which we can if it represents the running time of an algorithm), would this equation always be true?

Comment: $f(n)$ alone being nonnegative is not sufficient. If $g(n)=O(f(n))$ can  be negative (as in my counterexample), then you are still in trouble. If both $f$ and $g$ are nonnegative and $g=O(f)$, then, of course, $f+g=\theta(f)$.